# How to prove for an arbitrary distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Assume we have some distribution $P(x, y)$ on $\mathbb{X} \times \mathbb{Y}$, how to show that:

$$
\mathbb{E}_{x, y} \Bigl[
    \bigl(
        y - \mathbb{E}[y \mid x]
    \bigr)
    \bigl(
        \mathbb{E}[y \mid x] - f(x)
    \bigr)
\Bigr] = 0\text{ ?}
$$

My proof for discrete distributions (correct if it is not true):

\begin{align*}
                \mathbb{E}_{x, y} \Bigl[
                 \bigl(
                  y - \mathbb{E}[y \mid x]
                 \bigr)
                 \bigl(
                  \mathbb{E}[y \mid x] - f(x)
                 \bigr)
                \Bigr]
                =
                \mathbb{E}_{x, y} \Bigl[
                 y \mathbb{E}[y \mid x]
    \Bigr]
    -
                \mathbb{E}_{x, y} \Bigl[
                 \mathbb{E}[y \mid x]^2
    \Bigr]
    -\\
    -
                \mathbb{E}_{x, y} \Bigl[
                 y f(x)
    \Bigr]
    +
                \mathbb{E}_{x, y} \Bigl[
                 \mathbb{E}[y \mid x] f(x)
    \Bigr]
    =
    \sum_{\mathbb{X}}\sum_{\mathbb{Y}}y\mathbb{E}[y \mid x]P(x, y)
    -\\
    -
    \mathbb{E}_{x, y} \Bigl[
                 \mathbb{E}[y \mid x]^2
    \Bigr]
    -
    \sum_{\mathbb{X}}\sum_{\mathbb{Y}}yf(x)P(x, y)
    +
    \sum_{\mathbb{X}}\sum_{\mathbb{Y}}\mathbb{E}[y \mid x]f(x)P(x, y)
    =\\
    =
    \sum_{\mathbb{X}}\mathbb{E}[y \mid x]P(x)\sum_{\mathbb{Y}}y\frac{P(x, y)}{P(x)}
    -
    \sum_{\mathbb{X}}\mathbb{E}[y \mid x]^2\sum_{\mathbb{Y}}P(x, y)
    -\\
    -
    \sum_{\mathbb{X}}f(x)P(x)\sum_{\mathbb{Y}}y\frac{P(x, y)}{P(x)}
    +
    \sum_{\mathbb{X}}f(x)\mathbb{E}[y \mid x]\sum_{\mathbb{Y}}P(x, y)
\end{align*}
and
$$
\mathbb{E}[y \mid x] = \sum_{\mathbb{Y}}y\frac{P(x, y)}{P(x)},\sum_{\mathbb{Y}}P(x, y) = P(x).
$$

So how to make it for arbitrary distribution?

Comment: Replace the sums by integrals, the P's by dP's and the probability mass functions by probability density functions... ? (A measure theoretic proof is a bit more involved, but you've got the essence of the proof!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your so called "elementary" proof lost me hence here is a simpler, more general, approach. For *every* random variables $(X,Y)$, $Y$ integrable, consider $Z=Y-E(Y\mid X)$.

A *defining property* of the conditional expectation $E(Y\mid X)$ is that $E(Yg(X))=E(E(Y\mid X)g(X))$ for every measurable function $g$ such that the expectation exists, hence $E(Zg(X))=0$.

Now, $E(Y\mid X)=h(X)$ for some measurable function $h$ hence the choice $g=h-f$ proves the assertion in your post.